# Query mysql record and convert to array using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a help in getting a certain record from MySQL table and then convert it to an array.  I have two MySQL tables:

```
Table(1)name: **sent_msg** ... with the following columns:
serial
tonum
fromch


Table(2)name: **channel** ... with the following columns:
serial
phone
```

the fromch at `table(1)` matches serial at `table(2)`.  The record I want to get is **tonum**.

Please advice.

Regards.

Comment: first get the rows of channel tables serial values to an array and then look for the matching value with sent_msg tables formch column by looping through the serial values array and get your tonum value.

Comment: @koli can you please help by giving the php code ... please.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM channel LEFT JOIN send_msg ON channel.serial = sent_msg.fromch`

Comment: @BenHarold ... is the following true: SELECT tonum FROM channel LEFT JOIN send_msg ON channel.serial = sent_msg.fromch

Comment: What you know from those 4 fields? How you want to find the record?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to make a connection using`$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "INSERT_MYSQL_PASSOWRD", "DATABASE") or die(mysqli_error());`

After that, make a query using php through: `$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition");`

Last step is to convert it into a query:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

$array is now a multidimensional php array. Hope this helped.